# cdk: Unable to resolve AWS account to use

Tags: aws-cdk, localstack

I've configured a profile into my `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials`.

I'm able to run comands agains my localstack using `aws cli`:

```
$ aws cloudformation list-stacks --profile localstack --no-paginate --output json | jq .
{
  "StackSummaries": []
}
```

As you can see, `aws cli` is able to connect to my localstack and get (and empty) result. I've not deployed any stack yet.

When I'm trying to deploy my stack I'm getting:

```
$ cdk deploy --profile localstack
  Synthesis time: 16.94s


 ❌ Deployment failed: Error: Unable to resolve AWS account to use. It must be either configured when you define your CDK Stack, or through the environment
    at SdkProvider.resolveEnvironment (/home/jcabre/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:384:14622)

Unable to resolve AWS account to use. It must be either configured when you define your CDK Stack, or through the environment
```

Comment: Refer to the localstack docs on how to use CDK with localstack: https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/integrations/aws-cdk/